# Why doesn't DirectoryInfo have a Copy() method?

Tags: c#, oop, directory

DirectoryInfo has a `MoveTo` method, but no `Copy` method.

If I were pressed to omit one or the other (perhaps someone is going around saying 'too many methods!'), it would have to be `MoveTo`. Users of the class would still be able to achieve the same effect by calling `Copy` and then `Delete(true)` (true here indicating to delete contents recursively).

By comparison, it's much more involved to implement a `Copy` procedure from the existing methods.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

See ["Access denied" when using copyFile function, however, "moveFile" is working fine on the same directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168574/access-denied-when-using-copyfile-function-however-movefile-is-working-fin)

The WinAPI does not have a native call to copy directories. You need to transverse the directory and copy the structure manually. There are multiple ways to do this depending upon what time complexity characteristics you want.

Comment: It does, actually.  Also exposed in .NET in [everybody's favorite namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That's neat. It uses [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) under the hood which is a shell operation. It falls back on a directory transversal when there is no shell.